# Image tag is not showing image while image url is fine. MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I am new to asp.net MVC. I have the image source in database with the following:

```
@Model.Image2Url = "C:\Users\vasamad\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\ReactMVC\ReactMVC\Content\Images\Products\3.jpg"
```

I am adding it to view like this

```
<img src="@Model.Image2Url" alt="No Image"/>
```

in browser inspect Element "Could Not load the image"
when I copy this URL and past in new tab its showing the image.

Comment: * My image tag is fine.. this is just typing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store a relative image path to your MVC application root:

```
~/Content/Images/Products/3.jpg
```

If you want full image paths then you will need to write a controller action that will read this image from the absolute path and stream it to the response. Finally the `<img>` tag will need to point to this new controller action. Here's an example:

```
public ActionResult MyImage()
{
    // Get this from your database
    string absoluteImagePath = "C:\\Users\\vasamad\\Documents\\VisualStudio2015\\Projects\\ReactMVC\\ReactMVC\\Content\\Images\\Products\\3.jpg";
    return File(absoluteImagePath, "image/jpeg");
}
```

and then in your view point the image tag to this action:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("MyImage", "MyController")" alt="" />
```

Comment: How can i save the relative image path?
 var ImagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Products/") + img.FileName);
?????